# c# culture info conversion

Tags: c#, javascript, culture, cultureinfo

I need a way in c# or javascript to convert any input user has entered into invariant culture.
So if user enters 2,5 or 2.5 I wan't to convert it to decimal as 2.5.
Is there any way of doing this except of string.replace(",",".") ? :D
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) for you input field